# Using an escaped quote and then braces in interpolated string

Tags: scala, escaping, string-interpolation

I'm writing an (interpolated) string which has commonly-understood `{thing}` portions which the user should understand as placeholders for expected input. Since there's no leading `$`, I figured the curly braces would be interpreted literally.

**First attempt: curly braces**

```
val name = "Michael"
println(s"Hi, $name! Please enter your birthday in the form \"{month} {day}\".")
```

IntelliJ IDEA gives me no reason to worry. Looks like a plain old string:

[image: IDE showing words "form \"{month} {day}\"" with no special formatting on the words in brackets]

But I receive an error:

> not found: *value* month

**Second attempt: square braces**

Fine, curly braces are a bad idea. What about square braces?

```
val name = "Michael"
println(s"Hi, $name! Please enter your birthday in the form \"[month] [day]\".")
```

Again, IDEA's formatting leads me to expect the braces will be interpreted literally.

But I receive a different error:

> not found: *type* month

**Third attempt: remove escaped quotes**

Now I'm grasping at straws. I'll kill off the escaped quotes.

```
val name = "Michael"
println(s"Hi, $name! Please enter your birthday in the form {month} {day}.")
println(s"Hi, $name! Please enter your birthday in the form [month] [day].")
```

It works! Not formatted exactly as I would like, but enough to get the point across.

So, **my question**: why? Why does an escaped double-quote have any effect on the interpretation (and compilation) of these strings?

Obviously this won't derail my coding, but it is puzzling and counter-intuitive (to me). I'd love to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug in scala - [escape does not work with string interpolation](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6476).

it has nothing to do with braces. scala thinks, that string ends just after 1st escaped quote and can't find the following `month` value